# Problems with ListView colors

Tags: android, android-listview

this is how I like that the application be

[image]

but when I slip a finger through the list it looks like

[image]

how do I change from black to transparent? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe in the XML file in the part where your transparency will be.

```
    android:background="#66000000" android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

First 2 numbers control transparency.